# "I was bornt with" and "like to have"

Tags: grammaticality, tense

> I feel that fun-loving nature is what I **was bornt** with. When I look
>   back when I was a child, I **like** to have fun with other kids.

Is it correct to say

> I was **bornt with**

other possibilities could be 'I **have been bornt** with'

> When I look back when I was a child, I **like** to have fun with other
>   kids.

Is this sentence grammatically correct, would it be more correct if I say 'I **liked** to have fun with other kids'

Comment: What is the source of this sentence?

Comment: @Sydney I crafted it, there is no source.

Comment: *Bornt* is not the standard English past participle of "be born." Your subordinate clause says that your looking back took place when you were a child, but likely you mean when you look back now on the time of your childhood. Your independent clause is unmoored from your dependent clause, partly because of the different tenses in the two clauses and partly because your remembering isn't stated to have anything to do with your claim of current preference. Likely you mean, "When I look back at the time I was a child, I remember that I liked to have fun with other kids."

Answer (score 1):

As  user105719 has noted, 'bornt' is not a valid word.

The sentences should be something like:

> I feel that I was born with a fun-loving nature.
>   When I look back at my childhood, I liked to have fun with other kids.

Hope that helps,

Alan.

Answer (score 0):

An online search shows that 'bornt' is used for 'born' in one dialect in northern England, but it's totally not standard English. No-one says that, no-one writes that in standard English, and no standard dictionary includes it. Where did you hear or read it?

'was born' v 'have been born'. Present perfect 'have/has been born' is only used when there is a strong connection to 'now': 'The president's child has just been born!', or 'Last January, 26 children were born in this hospital [last January has finished]. Already this January, 35 have been born [this January is still 'now'].' You *were born* 20 or 30 or however many years ago.

You 'look back' at your childhood 'now' (or *when*) but 'your childhood' has finished, so everything in it is past tense, including the fact that you 'liked' to have fun with other kids.